# Google Cloud HTTPS Loadbalancer with NGINX shows different content each refresh

Tags: nginx, ssl, google-cloud-platform, https, load-balancing

I've recently set up a managed SSL GCP loadbalancer for my web app. The instance uses NGINX and serves all content correctly when accessing the HTTP IP of the instance itself. The content is structured as follows under /var/www/html in Ubuntu:

```
404.html  LICENSE.txt  browserconfig.xml  css  docs  humans.txt  img  index.html  js  manifest.json  robots.txt  service-worker.js
```

/css

```
main.css  normalize.css
```

/js

```
main.js  plugins.js  vendor
```

I am using the default NGINX sites-enabled file to serve content under /var/www/html.
My issue is, whenever I access the HTTPS DNS URL (https://example.com), only some of the files are loaded. Which files are loaded is changed on every refresh. For example, navigating to the site may load the index.html, the main.css, and the main.js, but not the normalize.css and service-worker.js. Refreshing the page could result in the site loading index.html, main.js, normalize.css, but not main.css, etc. Sometimes the index.html is not loaded, resulting in a 404 message that I assume is default on the loadbalancer. Networking tab shows 404 response for the files not loaded.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
For anyone that encounters something similar, I had two ports set for my instance group, 80 and 5000 for my api. These cannot be on the same named port, they must be separate. The loadbalancer was occasionally sending HTTPS requests to my backend Golang REST API because 5000 was open on the same named port.